# ipywidgets dropdown widgets: How to populate nested widgets based on selected dropdown option on onchange event?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, jupyter-irkernel

I am trying to build a widget that parses data from json and populates the tools, base form could contain simple input fields and a drop-down menu option. I want to add nested widgets based on the users choice for example as given below if the user wants an advanced parameter and select the "Full Parameter" option it should populate nested widgets (widget generated based on user input i.e. selected option)

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Dropdown

def dropdown_eventhandler(change):
    print(change.new)

option_list = ("Full Perameter", "Default Perameter")
dropdown = Dropdown(description="Choose one:", options=option_list)
dropdown.observe(dropdown_eventhandler, names='value')
display(dropdown)
```

I tried several things but, it didn't work. I tried to invoke the underlying widget by providing conditional parameters on the callback function.

Comment: Some similarities with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133865/generate-linked-dropdown-ipywidget-in-a-for-loop-one-per-multiindex-level

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your desired output:
If I understand correctly, you would like to have two nested dropdown list different options according to the chosen option in the outer dropdown.

```
option_list = ["Full Parameter", "Default Parameter"]
full_parameter = ['a', 'b', 'c']
default_parameter = ['d', 'e', 'f']
def option1(option_1):
    if option_1 == 'Full Parameter':
        def option2(option_2):
            print(option_2)
        wg.interact(option2, option_2=full_parameter)
    elif option_1 == 'Default Parameter':
        def option2(option_2):
            print(option_2)
        wg.interact(option2, option_2=default_parameter)
wg.interact(option1, option_1=option_list)
```

So the code above basically means that you have 2 dropdown list, the option shown in the second dropdown depends to the option chosen in the first dropdown. If you choose "Full Parameter" in the first dropdown, the options in the second dropdown are a, b, c. If you choose "Default Parameter", the options in the second dropdown are d, e, f.

Did I understand your question correctly?