# Generate linked dropdown ipywidget in a for loop -> one per multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas, drop-down-menu, multi-index, ipywidgets

I would like to select part of a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame to apply some post-processing (mainly to plot some graphs).

To do so, I would like to use one DropDown ipywidgets per MultiIndex level. And I would like to have a function capable of generate this widgets no matter the number of levels the DataFrame have.

Let's assume we have the following DataFrame (MultiIndex with 3 levels):

```
d = {'num_legs': [4, 4, 2, 2],
 'num_wings': [0, 0, 2, 2],
 'class': ['mammal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'bird'],
 'animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'bat', 'penguin'],
 'locomotion': ['walks', 'walks', 'flies', 'walks']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index(['class', 'locomotion', 'animal'])
```

I would like to have a first dropdown widget allowing to choose among "mammal" or "bird". The second dropdown widget, will then allow the choice among "walks" and "flies" depending on the first choice (actually, choosing bird will give only "walks" as possible choice because of DataFrame data). The third one would propose the available animals depending on the previous choices.

Here follows my code...nearly working : the first two dropdowns interact correctly but the subsequent ones keeps staying empty...

```
def multi_index_dropdown(df,n_of_levels_to_expands=None) :

n_of_levels_to_expands = df.index.nlevels
dd = {}

dd[0] = widgets.Dropdown(options=df.index.unique(level=0),
                                 description=df.index.names[0],
                                 disabled=False)
def make_update(ln) :
    def update_level(*args) :
        dd[ln].options = df.loc[dd[ln-1].value].index.unique(level=0)
    return update_level

update_levels = {}

for level_n in range(1,n_of_levels_to_expands) :
    dd[level_n] = widgets.Dropdown(description=df.index.names[level_n],
                                   disabled=False)

    update_levels[level_n] = make_update(level_n)
    
    dd[level_n-1].observe(update_levels[level_n],'value')

display(dd[0],dd[1],dd[2])

return dd
choice = multi_index_dropdown(df)
```

What's going wrong here?
Additional information:

- I am working with jupyter lab (I do not think this is important...).
- This is the first time I use a function (make_update) to create function in a for loop. However, I understood it was useful to pass the proper "level_n" argument...hoping I used it right!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was just an error in the `update_level` function (I did not undo some changes I made to simplify my problem) :

It should have been as follows :

```
    def update_level(*args) :
        xs = tuple(dd[i].value for i in range(ln))
        dd[ln].options = df.loc[xs].index.unique(level=0)
```

By the time, I have restructured my function in a class. The whole working code is the following :

```
class multi_index_dropdown(object) :

def __init__(self, df, n_of_levels_to_expands=None) :
    if n_of_levels_to_expands is None :
        self.n_of_levels_to_expands = df.index.nlevels
    else:
        self.n_of_levels_to_expands = n_of_levels_to_expands
    
    self.multiple_dd = {}
    self.df = df

    self.create()
    
def make_update(self,ln) :
    def update_level(*args) :
        xs = tuple(self.multiple_dd[i].value for i in range(ln))
        self.multiple_dd[ln].options = self.df.loc[xs].index.unique(level=0)
    return update_level
            
def create(self) :
    self.multiple_dd[0] = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=self.df.index.unique(level=0),
        description=self.df.index.names[0],
        disabled=False)

    self.update_levels = {}

    for level_n in range(1,self.n_of_levels_to_expands) :
        self.multiple_dd[level_n] = widgets.Dropdown(
            description=self.df.index.names[level_n],
            disabled=False)

        self.update_levels[level_n] = self.make_update(level_n)

        self.multiple_dd[level_n-1].observe(self.update_levels[level_n],'value')

    display(self.multiple_dd[0],self.multiple_dd[1],self.multiple_dd[2])

choice = multi_index_dropdown(df)
```